# In raywenderlich's core data tutorial, the app crash with this: Could not cast value of type 'Bow_Ties.Bow_TiesBowtie' to 'Bow_Ties.Bowtie'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In the tutorial, it said I should manually change the entity's class name from "Bowtie" to "Bow_Ties.Bowtie", namely *project name* + *class name*, or *namespace* + *class name* in the entity editor. Problem is when I changed the class name as instructed and pressed `enter`, the `.` between *project name* and *class name* just disappeared! Dunno if this was because of different Xcode versions. I was using Xcode 11 and swift5.1, while the tutorial was v2, the swift version maybe swift3 or earlier.

If I had not changed the class name, there would prompt a multiple commands error when compiling. If I did, when I was making a fetch request with core data as this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Bowtie> = Bowtie.fetchRequest()
let ties = try? ctx.fetch(request)
```

The second line would cause a `signal SIGABRT` crash, and the crash error was the same as the title. Only if I reedited my code as below it was able to build:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Bow_TiesBowtie> = Bow_TiesBowtie.fetchRequest()
let ties = try? ctx.fetch(request)
```

This is too weird for me to understand because when saving data with core data, the class I was using was `Bowtie` rather than `Bow_TiesBowtie`. The code is as below, which ran perfectly:

```
let bt = Bowtie(entity: entity!, insertInto: ctx)
bt.name = "My Bow Tie"
bt.lastWorn = Date()
try? ctx.save()
```

Was I doing something out of sense? Any suggestion is welcome!  <3

---------- Edited ----------

My issues I conclude as these below:

1. An entity with the default class name, which is exactly as the entity name and the auto-generated NSManagedObject model class name, would fail the compiling (both generated model class would compile to the same .o file), as below

[fail on Multiple commands produce the same Mach-o file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/446ld.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFfs6.png

2. If I prefix the entity's class name with the project name(namespace or main bundle name), it compiles, but would crash to the point where the fetch request is executed, with the message `Could not cast value of type 'Bow_Ties.Bow_TiesBowtie' (0x...) to 'Bow_Ties.Bowtie' (0x...).`. Bowtie is the entity name as well as the generated NSManagedObject class name, and Bow_TiesBowtie is the prefixed entity class name. Meanwhile, writing data with the class Bowtie runs perfectly.

[prefixed entity class name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mFm.png)

[fetch request crashed the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/446ld.png)

3. With the prefixed entity class name, if I use the the NSManagedObjec `Bow_TiesBowtie` instead of `Bowtie`, everything runs good. Btw, I never made the `Bow_TiesBowtie` class, it was auto-generated from the prefixed entity class name I think. I even don't have a `.swift` file with this name on my disk.

Comment: Why are you following such an old tutorial to start with? There must be many more recent ones to choose from. It is not clear to me why you want to rename the entity, please re-write the question without any reference to the tutorial so that it can be read as a stand alone question without us having to know about a specific external resource.

Comment: Your fetch request references something called `Bow_TiesBowtie` Surely that's your error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You need not refer to the rw tutorial to understand my issue. Just wanna explain how it occured. I use this old tutorial because I got it from a friend and I myself have no way to update it.

Comment: @Magnas I'm sure it was not my error. I have made it clear that if I should use Bowtie as the fetch request result, the app would crash because of `signal SIGABRT`, with the message of `Could not cast value of type 'Bow_Ties.Bow_TiesBowtie' to 'Bow_Ties.Bowtie'`

Comment: @Magnas This `Bow_TiesBowtie` existed because I changed the class of the entity to this one in the entity editor. Why I did this was because if I wouldn't, the app could not even compile -- it would fail because more than one Mach-o file would be generated if the class name of the entity was left default, namely Bowtie.

Comment: That’s the problem, a question should be self contained so to speak so a reader does _not_ have to go to a external page/source to understand it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thx for your suggestion. See the edited plz. No reference needed. <3